# Why I unable to access the static file in nginx?

Tags: nginx, static

My html code is given below, i want to put the video file in the media and image file in static but my nginx setup is not showing images but able to show me html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello world !!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit dolorum minima voluptatibus veniam enim, aut aspernatur voluptate consectetur quod obcaecati ipsa, ea assumenda eos impedit quisquam necessitatibus similique, dolor nesciunt ducimus perspiciatis! Ullam facilis fuga temporibus blanditiis earum perferendis adipisci?</p>
    <img src="static/image.jpeg" alt="" style="width: 300px;">
    <img src="static/hello.jpg" alt="">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="/media/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video> 
</body>
</html>
```

ngnix sites_available

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /home/ibex/www/;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        root /home/ibex/www/data;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
        root /home/ibex/www/static/;
  }
}
```

This is the folder structure
[image: folder sructure]

This is the output on the browser
[image: browser output]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove an `*` symbol from this line:

`location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {`

Refer to the first example here [serving static content](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)

Comment: still not working after removing the ```*```